# How find maximum values for two columns separately for groups in R?

Tags: r

Here example of dataset dput()

```
dd=structure(list(perc = c(50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 110L, 115L, 
120L, 130L, 140L, 150L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 80L, 85L, 90L, 95L, 96L, 
97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 110L, 115L, 
120L, 130L, 140L, 150L), mdm = c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), price = c(38.9, 46.68, 54.46, 62.24, 
66.13, 70.02, 73.91, 74.688, 75.466, 76.244, 77.022, 77.8, 78.578, 
79.356, 80.134, 80.912, 81.69, 85.58, 89.47, 93.36, 101.14, 108.92, 
116.7, 38.9, 46.68, 54.46, 62.24, 66.13, 70.02, 73.91, 74.688, 
75.466, 76.244, 77.022, 77.8, 78.578, 79.356, 80.134, 80.912, 
81.69, 85.58, 89.47, 93.36, 101.14, 108.92, 116.7), count = c(175, 
160, 145, 130, 122.5, 115, 107.5, 106, 104.5, 103, 101.5, 100, 
98.5, 97, 95.5, 94, 92.5, 85, 77.5, 70, 55, 40, 25, 175, 160, 
145, 130, 122.5, 115, 107.5, 106, 104.5, 103, 101.5, 100, 98.5, 
97, 95.5, 94, 92.5, 85, 77.5, 70, 55, 40, 25), rev = c(6807.5, 
7468.8, 7896.7, 8091.2, 8100.925, 8052.3, 7945.325, 7916.928, 
7886.197, 7853.132, 7817.733, 7780, 7739.933, 7697.532, 7652.797, 
7605.728, 7556.325, 7274.3, 6933.925, 6535.2, 5562.7, 4356.8, 
2917.5, 6807.5, 7468.8, 7896.7, 8091.2, 8100.925, 8052.3, 7945.325, 
7916.928, 7886.197, 7853.132, 7817.733, 7780, 7739.933, 7697.532, 
7652.797, 7605.728, 7556.325, 7274.3, 6933.925, 6535.2, 5562.7, 
4356.8, 2917.5), seb = c(4200L, 3840L, 3480L, 3120L, 2940L, 2760L, 
2580L, 2544L, 2508L, 2472L, 2436L, 2400L, 2364L, 2328L, 2292L, 
2256L, 2220L, 2040L, 1860L, 1680L, 1320L, 960L, 600L, 4200L, 
3840L, 3480L, 3120L, 2940L, 2760L, 2580L, 2544L, 2508L, 2472L, 
2436L, 2400L, 2364L, 2328L, 2292L, 2256L, 2220L, 2040L, 1860L, 
1680L, 1320L, 960L, 600L), profit = c(2607.5, 3628.8, 4416.7, 
4971.2, 5160.925, 5292.3, 5365.325, 5372.928, 5378.197, 5381.132, 
5381.733, 5380, 5375.933, 5369.532, 5360.797, 5349.728, 5336.325, 
5234.3, 5073.925, 4855.2, 4242.7, 3396.8, 2317.5, 2607.5, 3628.8, 
4416.7, 4971.2, 5160.925, 5292.3, 5365.325, 5372.928, 5378.197, 
5381.132, 5381.733, 5380, 5375.933, 5369.532, 5360.797, 5349.728, 
5336.325, 5234.3, 5073.925, 4855.2, 4242.7, 3396.8, 2317.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))
```

I need  find for each group `mdm` the maximum value for the columns `rev` and `profit`.
For example  for `mdm = 7`, the maximum value for `rev = 8100.925` at the `price level = 66.13`
and the maximum `profit value = 5369.532` at the `price level = 79.356`.
For mdm=8 similarly.

So as desired output would be something like this (perc column must be in output)

```
perc mdm    price   count     profit           perc price   rev
102 7      79,356     97       5369,532        85   66,13   8100,925
102 8      79,356     97       5369,532        85   66,13   8100,925
```

What the easy way get desired output?
Thank you for very valuable help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the grouping and filtering separately, and then join them together on "mdm":

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(
  select(dd, mdm, rev, perc, price, count) %>%
    group_by(mdm) %>%
    filter(rev==max(rev)),
  select(dd, mdm, profit, perc, price, count) %>%
    group_by(mdm) %>%
    filter(profit==max(profit)), 
  by="mdm", suffix = c(".rev", ".profit"))
```

---

```
# A tibble: 2 x 9
# Groups:   mdm [2]
    mdm   rev perc.rev price.rev count.rev profit perc.profit price.profit count.profit
  <int> <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>       <int>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1     7 8101.       85      66.1      122.  5382.          99         77.0         102.
2     8 8101.       85      66.1      122.  5382.          99         77.0         102.
```

Can also use `slice_max`.